# Closing postgres connection using psql when executed from shell script

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, psql

How to close connection using psql when executed from shell script

Answer (score 3):

If you run

```sh
psql -c '/* SQL statement */'
```

or

```sh
psql -f script.sql
```

the connection will automatically be closed as soon as the command is done

Comment: Laurenz Albe, Thanks for your answer, i have scheduled job through jenkins, which hit my postgres DB in every 1 hour and in between i am getting this error "Failed to get SSH fingerprint from DB: pq: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections" I doubt it could be because script does not closing the connection. according to your answer, it should close the connection, any idea why i am getting this error?

Comment: There are many other connections to the database. Examine `pg_stat_activity` to find out where they come from.